# Partially applied function in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand Partially applied function in scala

```
scala> val a=sum _
a: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>

scala> a(1,2,3)
res7: Int = 6
```

I am just giving this `val a=sum _`

I want to understand how scala interprets it will take 3 arguments

```
a: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just experienced the `eta-expansion` that is converting a `method` into a `function`.

Your method is `sum` which you are not demonstrating but based on the function version must be:

```
def sum(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int):Int = a + b + c
```

The underscore you are adding at the end is converting your method into a function as the descriptive type signature of the result shows: `(Int, Int, Int) => Int`

This way you are converting your method into a *function value* that can be assigned to a variable and passed around in your application logic conveying a behavioural change to your data (addition in your instance).

Comment: What is the difference between method and function in this use-case?

Comment: Added info as per to why and what this is achieving in the method/function context.

Comment: @AvihooMamka The difference between Scala methods and functions is mainly in how are they translate to respective JVM world. Scala Methods are same as Java methods and they either exist as members of an instance or in static context. Whereas Scala functions are themselves instances of `Function1`, `Function2` or `FunctionN` class depending on the number of arguments.